# Show an entire DataFrame in a Julia Jupyter Notebook with Nice formatting

Tags: dataframe, julia, jupyter-notebook

I have a rather large dataframe (roughly 200 rows). Whenever I attempt to use `showall(df)` it prints the entire dataframe, but uses ASCII and does not format nicely. Is there any way to get an entire dataframe to show with the same formatting as is in the following screenshot?
[image]

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: An example of what `showall(df)` outputs is shown below.

│ Row │ Category                       │ Month_0 │ Month_1 │ Month_2 │ Month_3 │ Month_4 │ Month_5 │ Month_6 │ Month_7 │ Month_8 │ Month_9 │ Month_10 │ Month_11 │ Month_12 │
├─────┼────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ "Environmental - Phase 1)"     │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │
│ 2   │ "Design (AIA/MEP/Struct)"      │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │
│ 3   │ "Well Capping"                 │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │
│ 4   │ "Landscape Design"             │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │
│ 5   │ "Legal / Accounting"           │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │ 0.0      │
│ 6   │ "Permits / Plan Checks"        │ 0       │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │

Comment: Do you have a example of  ".. uses ASCII and does not format nicely". If I try to do this using iris dataset (RDatasets) it looks ok to me.

Comment: I post an example a little bit later, I am not currently at my computer.

Comment: @AndreiR I added what the output looks like. Imgur would not allow me to upload an image so I pasted it as plain text.

Comment: Alejandro maybe you can check https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/886 . Bottom line, instead of showall you can use ENV["LINES"]=200 or whatever number of rows you need and simply type  df and enter.

Comment: @AndreiR Thank you! I will try this tomorrow, I suspect it will solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreiR It worked! Post it as an answer so you can get the credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can check this [issue](http://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/issues/886).

Bottom line, instead of showall you can use:

ENV["LINES"]=200

or whatever number of rows you need and simply type df and enter.